# Create ubercart ordes for users

Tags: ubercart, views

I need to create ubercart orders for a bunch of users. Can this be done with views and VBO or do I need to make a custom module for that?

Comment: Did you try it in VBO?  Yes, it probably can, but of course it depends on the details of your setup...

Answer (score 0):

You would need to create a custom module for this as you want to create X number of orders for X number of users. Reason why you need a custom module is because each order is its own node with a bunch of references to other data on the site. Doing this in bulk would require you to know all the tables data that are updated and inserted when an order is created.